# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required file.php

Tags: php, path, set-include-path

I've a site that runs on my local machine. These rows are ok when I'm on OSX. While on windows generates errors:

```
set_include_path ( get_include_path () . ':' . dirname ( __FILE__ ) . '/../lib/propel/runtime/lib/' );
set_include_path ( get_include_path () . ':' . dirname ( __FILE__ ) . '/../lib/smarty/libs/' );
set_include_path ( get_include_path () . ':' . dirname ( __FILE__ ) . '/../classes/' );
set_include_path ( get_include_path () . ':' . dirname ( __FILE__ ) . '/../classes/ORM/' );
```

This is the error

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Propel.php'
>   (include_path='.:C:/wamp/www/emporio-rossi/conf/:C:\wamp\www\emporio-rossi\wapp/../lib/propel/runtime/lib/:C:\wamp\www\emporio-rossi\wapp/../lib/smarty/libs/:C:\wamp\www\emporio-rossi\wapp/../classes/:C:\wamp\www\emporio-rossi\wapp/../classes/ORM/')
>   in C:\wamp\www\emporio-rossi\wapp\conf.inc.php on line 33

Propel.php is located in the firs URI (`set_include_path ( get_include_path () . ':' . dirname ( __FILE__ ) . '/../lib/propel/runtime/lib/' );`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows uses `;` as a path separator whereas nix (including OSX) uses `:`.

The answer is to use the `PATH_SEPARATOR` constant:

```
set_include_path ( get_include_path () . PATH_SEPARATOR . dirname ( __FILE__ ) . '/../lib/propel/runtime/lib/' );
```

From [the docs](https://www.php.net/set_include_path):

> Making use of the PATH_SEPARATOR constant, it is possible to extend the include path regardless of the operating system.